# Tkinter how to display image and not move any content around?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 800)

# Add a grid
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)

directory = "C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
tk.Label(mainframe, text="Choose your sign off here:").grid(row=1, column=1)
popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)

label2 = tk.Label(mainframe, image=None)
label2.grid(row=4, column=0)

# On change dropdown callback.
def change_dropdown(*args):
    """ Updates label2 image. """
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    img = img.resize((240,250))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)


tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open", command=change_dropdown).grid(row=3, column=1)

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1).grid(column = 2, row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="May Contain Statement.", variable=var2).grid(column = 2, row=2, sticky=W)
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Cocoa Content (%).", variable=var3).grid(column = 2, row=3, sticky=W)
var4 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Vegetable fat in addition to Cocoa butter", variable=var4).grid(column = 2, row=4, sticky=W)
var5 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Instructions for Use.", variable=var5).grid(column = 2, row=5, sticky=W)
var6 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Additional warning statements (pitt/stone, hyperactivity etc)", variable=var6).grid(column = 2, row=6, sticky=W)
var7 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Nutritional Information Visible", variable=var7).grid(column = 2, row=7, sticky=W)
var8 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Storage Conditions", variable=var8).grid(column = 2, row=8, sticky=W)
var9 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Best Before & Batch Information", variable=var9).grid(column = 2, row=9, sticky=W)
var10 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Net Weight & Correct Font Size.", variable=var10).grid(column = 2, row=10, sticky=W)
var11 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Barcode - Inner", variable=var11).grid(column = 2, row=11, sticky=W)
var12 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Address & contact details correct", variable=var12).grid(column = 2, row=12, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

gives me the output of this:

[image]

The problem I am having is, when I choose a directory, open the image it stretches out all other content, I am wondering, how can I place the image next to the check-boxes and not move the check-boxes content?

Here is the output:

[image]

this is the output I am intending to get (used paint to edit):

[image]

Comment: It would have been more better if you added a working code

Comment: Working code is at the top

Comment: To make all the IntVar(s) in one glance, you can use this: `for i in range(1, 13):exec("var"+str(i)+" = IntVar()")`

Comment: ...or instead consider giving your variables names. `var4` is rarely a good idea, your code might be more manageable with a `vegetableFatFlag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `rowspan` option to your `label2` variable, as follows:

```
label2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, rowspan = 10)
```

Edit the `rowspan` value to get the desired result

Comment: Works with `column = 1`. Editing rowspan does nothing much

Comment: The problem that OP is facing is more related to Tkinter Grid Geometry. OP needs the image to span various rows, rather than **populate** a single one. So `rowspan` should lead to an ideal result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your window is supposed to consist of two independent columns. You can do this by nesting `Frame` objects. Starting with your main frame, put two frames side by side, like so:

```py
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
# configure your main frame here
leftframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
leftframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
rightframe = tk.Frame(mainframe)
rightframe.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

And now you can proceed to place your widgets around. For instance:

```py
# menu and label are supposed to be in the left column
tk.Label(leftframe, text="Choose your sign off here:").grid(row=0, column=0)
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(leftframe, tkvar, *choices)
# ...
# but you want the checkboxes on the right
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(rightframe, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
# ...
```

Please note the changes I made to `row` and `column` arguments. And of course, read the docs for the [Grid Geometry Manual](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), as Eduard mentioned.

Comment: Updated the making variables at once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970378/tkinter-how-to-display-image-and-not-move-any-content-around/57970489?noredirect=1#comment102352237_57970378